# networkD3 conflict with rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I have created a fairly large (multi-page) flexdashboard that includes different htmlwidgets (plotly, highcharts, leaflet, etc).

In order to avoid conflict between rCharts and other htmlwidgets, I included the javascript libraries mannually, excluding jQuery:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href=C:/Users/stefanj/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rCharts/libraries/nvd3/css/nv.d3.css>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href=C:/Users/stefanj/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rCharts/libraries/nvd3/css/rNVD3.css>
  <script type='text/javascript' src=C:/Users/stefanj/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rCharts/libraries/nvd3/js/d3.v3.min.js></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src=C:/Users/stefanj/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rCharts/libraries/nvd3/js/nv.d3.min-new.js></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src=C:/Users/stefanj/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rCharts/libraries/nvd3/js/fisheye.js></script>
```

Also, I set the rChart chunk to:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE,results='asis', eval = TRUE, include_assets = FALSE}
````

However, when I plot a simpleNetwork, it does not render if the rCharts are included in the flexboard.

Any ideas?

P.S. not sure what else to include to make the question more reproducible.

Comment: To have a _reproducible_ question try to use know and simple data sets like `iris` and find a simple combination of widgets which reproduce the problem. Not sure if this rcharts work nice with rest of htmlwidgets, have you tried highcharter instead?

Comment: yes. i actually use it in one of the charts. but i haven't really found anything as interactive as http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBar.html

Comment: All depends what you define interactive ;)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`networkD3` was updated to D3v4 in [version 0.3](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/blob/master/NEWS.md#03) in. Feb. 2017, which is not compatible with v3 versions of D3, which is what `rCharts` appears to use. `htmlwidgets`, which is the underlying package that drives `networkD3` and `rCharts`, only uses the most recent version of a dependency, so htmlwidgets that use conflicting versions of the same library can not both work. Check [here](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues/162) for a starting point of discussion about this problem.

You have a few possible options, though none of them are great...

1. revert `networkD3` to a version < 0.3 so that it also uses D3v3
2. lobby for the [`rCharts` developers](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts) to upgrade to D3v4
3. lobby for the [htmlwidgets` developers](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets) to come up with a robust way of dealing with conflicting JavaScript dependencies